# Fullpage js stops scrolling inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage js on my website and inside one of the sections I have included an iframe.

[example issue](http://forestpin.azurewebsites.net/)

If you move to the last section in the example above you can't scroll further down unless you scroll outside the iframe. I found that this method in fullpage can be used to move a section up. 
[fullpage method](https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/GJXNMN)

```
$(document).on('click', '#moveUp', function(){
$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
});
```

Also this code can be used to detect if the iframe has reached the bottom. 
[example iframe reaching bottom](http://jsfiddle.net/tfjxyyj2/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=tfjxyyj2)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) 
alert('Bottom reached');
});
```

The issue is discussed in this [link](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/819) as well but I cannot understand whats explained as the solution. 
How can I use these two examples to make the page scroll up and down after iframe reaches top or bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally expected.

If you want to make use of scrollable content then  you'll have to use the scrollOverflow option provided by fullpage.js See an example [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Otherwise you'll have to code yourself the detection of the scrollbar within that iframe and detect when it reaches the bottom of it, then call a fullpage.js function such as [`$.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown()`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#movesectiondown).

Answer (score 1):

Give iframe a name. get iframe.window. Then add scrollEvent listener